# Ionic 5, SMS Retriever, StartWatching() is not Working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm using this code from the documentation [Sms Retriever](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms-retriever)

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

    hash: any;
    Sms: any;
    constructor(private smsRetriever: SmsRetriever) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.smsRetriever.getAppHash()
            .then((res: any) => alert(res))
            .catch((error: any) => alert(error));

        this.smsRetriever.startWatching()
            .then((res: any) => alert(res))
            .catch((error: any) => alert(error));
    }
}
```

When I start the App and open the page on my Phone, then receive an SMS, nothing happens!

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: debug your app and check consoles for error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last comment on https://github.com/hanatharesh2712/ionic-native-sms-retriever-plugin-master/issues/3 , the plugin seems to work on signed version of the apk.

Comment: Please don't post only links.

Comment: @Akif While you are basically right to recommend against link-only answer, this one IS more than a link.